# Cannot ping alibaba ECS instance

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I have an ECS instance running in alibaba. When I try to ping from my local box it is not available.

How can I make the ECS instance pingable? The security group is allowing the ICMP

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple causes which can include

- The link between the terminal and the device has failed.
- The VPN link between the device and Alibaba Cloud has failed.
- The target ECS instance has failed.
- The service provider network has failed.

The procedure to fix this is mentioned here:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/94278.htm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change the rule priority order. On your screen, all of the three rules have priority 1.

If this is Windows ECS instance it might be a Windows Firewall who might block it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the Security Group rules are prohibiting pinging the instance or not.

If it is not then the issue may be at the OS level. Could you please verify the firewall settings? and Could you change the priority of rule?